# JavaScript - Having trouble parsing a json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have trouble parsing a JSON object,

this is my code

```
var k = '[{"image:loc":["https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0094/2252/products/YZY-KW3027.053.jpg?v=1539344090"],"image:title":["Yeezy WMNS Tubular Boot Washed Canvas - Limestone"]}]'
var kP = JSON.parse(k);

console.log(kP);
```

But when I do try to parse "image:loc" or "image:title" like this: `console.log(kP['image:loc']);`
it returns undefined.

Comment: Is there is only one image loc in array or it may be more than one ?

Answer (score 0):

Since `kP` is an array, to access any property from that you have to use proper *index*:

```js
var k = '[{"image:loc":["https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0094/2252/products/YZY-KW3027.053.jpg?v=1539344090"],"image:title":["Yeezy WMNS Tubular Boot Washed Canvas - Limestone"]}]'
var kP = JSON.parse(k);

console.log(kP);
console.log(kP[0]['image:loc']);
```

Comment: @BobJensen, you are most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(kP['image:loc']);` doesn't work as `kP` is an array. You need to target the first index of the array to target your object like so:

```js
var k = '[{"image:loc":["https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0094/2252/products/YZY-KW3027.053.jpg?v=1539344090"],"image:title":["Yeezy WMNS Tubular Boot Washed Canvas - Limestone"]}]'
var kP = JSON.parse(k);

console.log(kP[0]['image:loc']);
```